# How to wrap a C++ function that returns boost::optional<T>?

Tags: c++, boost-python

I want to wrap a function that returns a `boost::optional<T>`. That is, given:

```
class Foo {
    boost::optional<T> func();
};
```

I'd like to wrap that somehow so that Python either gets a `T` by value, or `None`:

```
class_<Foo>("Foo")
    .def("func", func, return_value_policy<return_boost_optional???>);
```

Normally if it just returned a `T`, I could use:

```
class_<Foo>("Foo")
    .def("func", func, return_value_policy<return_by_value>());
```

But since it returns a `boost::optional<T>`, it could also return `boost::none`, which I'd like to end up as Python's `None`.

Is there a way to do this with the existing converters? If not, is there some workaround to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [ResultConverter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/python/doc/v2/ResultConverter.html) concept is designed to solve this problem.  The [`return_value_policy`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/python/doc/v2/return_value_policy.html) CallPolicy model uses a ResultConverterGenerator to create a ResultConverter, and the ResultConverter is used to modify the return value of a function being exposed to Python.  In this case, a custom type that implements the ResultConverter concept could be used to either return Python `None` or instantiate an object with the appropriate Python class.  While the documentation list all the type requirements, it may be easier to understood with something closer resembling code:

```cpp
/// @brief The ResultConverterGenerator.
struct result_converter_generator
{
  template <typename T>
  struct apply
  {
    struct result_converter
    {
      // Must be default constructible.
      result_converter();

      // Return true if T can be converted to a Python Object.
      bool convertible();

      // Convert obj to a PyObject, explicitly managing proper reference
      // counts.
      PyObject* operator(const T& obj);

      // Returns the Python object that represents the type.  Used for
      // documentation.
      const PyTypeObject* get_pytype();
    };

    /// @brief The ResultConverter.
    typedef result_converter type;
  };
};
```

Often times, when creating a custom ResultConverter model, one can use template meta-programming to minimize the chances of runtime errors in conversions, and even catch errors at compile time and provide meaningful messages.  Here is a complete example of `return_optional`, a ResultConverter model that takes a C++ `boost::optional<T>` object, and converts it to the appropriate Python object.

```cpp
#include <boost/mpl/if.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/integral_constant.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/in_place_factory.hpp>

/// @brief Mockup model.
class spam {};

/// @brief Mockup factory for model.
boost::optional<spam> make_spam(bool x)
{
  return x ? boost::optional<spam>(boost::in_place()) : boost::none;
}

namespace detail {

/// @brief Type trait that determines if the provided type is
///        a boost::optional.
template <typename T>
struct is_optional : boost::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_optional<boost::optional<T> > : boost::true_type {};

/// @brief Type used to provide meaningful compiler errors.
template <typename>
struct return_optional_requires_a_optional_return_type {};

/// @brief ResultConverter model that converts a boost::optional object to
///        Python None if the object is empty (i.e. boost::none) or defers
///        to Boost.Python to convert object to a Python object.
template <typename T>
struct to_python_optional
{
  /// @brief Only supports converting Boost.Optional types.
  /// @note This is checked at runtime.
  bool convertible() const { return detail::is_optional<T>::value; }

  /// @brief Convert boost::optional object to Python None or a
  ///        Boost.Python object.
  PyObject* operator()(const T& obj) const
  {
    namespace python = boost::python;
    python::object result =
      obj                      // If boost::optional has a value, then
        ? python::object(*obj) // defer to Boost.Python converter.
        : python::object();    // Otherwise, return Python None.

    // The python::object contains a handle which functions as
    // smart-pointer to the underlying PyObject.  As it will go
    // out of scope, explicitly increment the PyObject's reference
    // count, as the caller expects a non-borrowed (i.e. owned) reference.
    return python::incref(result.ptr());
  }

  /// @brief Used for documentation.
  const PyTypeObject* get_pytype() const { return 0; }
};

} // namespace detail

/// @brief Converts a boost::optional to Python None if the object is
///        equal to boost::none.  Otherwise, defers to the registered
///        type converter to returs a Boost.Python object.
struct return_optional 
{
  template <class T> struct apply
  {
    // The to_python_optional ResultConverter only checks if T is convertible
    // at runtime.  However, the following MPL branch cause a compile time
    // error if T is not a boost::optional by providing a type that is not a
    // ResultConverter model.
    typedef typename boost::mpl::if_<
      detail::is_optional<T>,
      detail::to_python_optional<T>,
      detail::return_optional_requires_a_optional_return_type<T>
    >::type type;
  }; // apply
};   // return_optional

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<spam>("Spam")
    ;

  python::def("make_spam", &make_spam,
    python::return_value_policy<return_optional>());
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> assert(isinstance(example.make_spam(True), example.Spam))
>>> assert(example.make_spam(False) is None)
```

The compile time type checking occurs when the `return_optional` ResultConvert is attempted to be used with a function that returns a value that is not a `boost::optional`.  For instance, when the following is used:

```cpp
struct egg {};

egg* make_egg();

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::def("make_egg", &make_egg,
    python::return_value_policy<return_optional>());
}
```

The compiler will select select the `return_optional_requires_a_optional_return_type` implementation, and fail compilation.  Here is part of the compiler error message clang provides:

```
error: no member named 'get_pytype' in
'detail::return_optional_requires_a_optional_return_type<egg *>'
```

Comment: This should really be part of the boost::python library. Really nice!

Comment: This is a really phenomenal answer.